# What does "Did not retain recoil value on render, or committed after timeout elapsed. This is fine, but odd. undefined" mean? And how do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, recoiljs

I am running some react-testing-library tests and getting warnings for `Did not retain recoil value on render, or committed after timeout elapsed. This is fine, but odd. undefined`. What does this mean? And how do I fix it?

I have just added a new recoil atom.

I am using recoil 0.3.0.

Answer (score 7):

This is a well known issue that will be fixed in the next released. You can ignore this warning as mentioned in the [corresponding Github issue](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/1034#issuecomment-856323314). So there is no problem with your code its just a warning that recoil emits unnecessarily.

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't see that when I searched. I will eagerly await the next release.